# WSGI request and response wrappers

Tags: python, http, httprequest, wsgi, httpresponse

I'm looking for WSGI request and response wrappers for having a more convenient interface than the plain WSGI `environ` and `start_response` callback. I want something like [WebOb](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) or [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/). But I don't like WebOb's PHP-like usage of GET and POST for parameter dictionaries, because HTTP is not limited to GET and POST and the distinction is not necessary when accessing params.

What request/response wrapper do you prefer and why?

Answer (score 1):

WebOb allows you to access POST & GET parameters jointly by accessing `Request.str_params` attribute. Additionally, Request.method gives you acces to the HTTP request type which is not limited to POST or GET.

Comment: Exactly: WebOb just assigned those names to reflect how the URL-delivered parameters and body-delivered parameters are *usually* used. But `GET` and `POST` are still there regardless of what the actual HTTP method is, so that if someone does, say, a `PUT` then you can see the string `"PUT"` in `req.method` and can still get any parameters by looking at `req.GET`, `req.POST`, and `req.str_params`.

Comment: True, the notion of "`POST` params" and "`GET` params" is a little bit confusing. The former are parameters passed in the body of request, while the latter are those supplied in the URL. Their presence is not limited by the request method.